# Picking the right SQL Server collation for storage

Tags: sql-server, collation

How does the collation impact SQL Server in terms of storage and how does this affect the Unicode and non-unicode data types?

- Does the collation impact Unicode storage? or just govern sort rules within the database?
- When I use the non-unicode data types what restictions are tied to the collation?
- If restrictions apply, what happens when I try to store a character not in database collation of a non-unicode data type?

My understanding is that the Unicode data type can always store the full set of Unicode data while the non-unicode data types storage capabilties depend on the code page (which is defined by the collation) and can only represent a number of common characters in that collation.

Obviously each character in an Unicode data type would at least occupy 2 bytes while the non-unicode data types occupy 1 byte per character (or does this vary with collation as well?)

Set me straight here, how does this work exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server stores Unicode data (NTEXT, NVARCHAR) in UCS2, always resulting in 2 bytes per character.

A collation only affects sorting (and casing).

In non-Unicode data types (TEXT, VARCHAR), only a single byte is used per character, and only characters of the collation's code page can be stored (just as you stated). See this [MSDN article on collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28SQL.80%29.aspx)